# Не вызывается AlertDialog из другого класса

Tags: android, java

Суть вопроса такова: создал кастомный диалог, в нем будут выводиться настройки некого плеера, то есть из n-количества форм будет вызываться. В связи с этим решил вывести этот диалог в отдельный класс, но никак не могу его оттуда запустить. Хотя из локального  активити он запускается хорошо.

Вот это класс с вынесенным диалогом:

```
public class MusicDialog extends Activity {

final int DIALOG = 1;
public LinearLayout view;       
public Dialog dial;
public Context contG;

public  MusicDialog (Context cont){
     contG=cont;
}

  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(contG);
    adb.setTitle("Custom dialog");
    // создаем view из dialog.xml
    view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    // устанавливаем ее, как содержимое тела диалога
    adb.setView(view);
    // находим TexView для отображения кол-ва
   // tvCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    return adb.create();
  }

}
```

Вот так пытаюсь вызвать:
          public void onclick(View v) {
            //btn = v.getId();

```
         muDai = new MusicDialog(getApplicationContext());
         muDai.showDialog(1);
      }
```

вылетает на строке
    view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

логи вылета на return adb.create():

```
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9089)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     ... 11 more
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:553)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:243)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at com.example.dial2.MusicDialog.onCreateDialog(MusicDialog.java:44)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2541)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:906)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2623)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2583)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     at com.example.dial2.MainActivity.onclick(MainActivity.java:37)
12-10 12:37:55.601: E/AndroidRuntime(8902):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: это вообще неправильно, неправильно выность код диалога, как активити. ты должен сделать extends Dialog, и уже вызывать его

Comment: Простите.. только учусь.

Comment: Благодарю! Эта строка заработала, но теперь крах на 
     return adb.create();

Comment: ты бы еще логи выкладывал...

Comment: логи в шапке

Comment: ну теперь читай мой первый коммент и делай правильно =)

Answer (score 2):

Замени

```
view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
```

на

```
view = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
```